# How can I change the cursor position of the user input in input() function in Python?

Tags: python, input

While using the `input()` function I want to take or receive a string from the user to a variable. So is it possible to input inside square brackets instead of plain text? For example;

```
a = input("-->")
```

this shows the output like this:

```
-->
```

but instead can I have the output like this:

```
--> [ _ ]
```

and take the input inside the square bracket. (`_` represents the cursor.)

Comment: You want the user input inside brackets? For example:
Out[1]: -->[ input_here ]

Comment: Are you limited to `input`? You can get around this using the `curses` module otherwise.

Comment: @Alexander I don't know how does curses work. There are some answers related to curses but I cannot understand those, and I am not able to import curses module too.

Answer (score 3):

Manipulating the cursor position when you call `input()` requires a hack with ANSI escape sequences. (See @chepner's answer.) To do what you want more correctly, you need to use a library that can manipulate the terminal, such as [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html).

Comment: Not entirely correct, but I've upvoted because my own answer isn't really appropriate for "real" applications; `curses` is.

Comment: @chepner Thanks for your support. Reworded for more technical accuracy. Feel free to suggest improvements.

Answer (score 2):

You can, sort of. If your terminal supports ANSI escape sequences, you can save the current cursor position by outputting `\033[s` and move the cursor back to the last saved position with `\033[u`. Then your call to `input` will look like

```
a = input("--> [\033[s ]\033[u")
```

However, this is purely visual: nothing stops you from typing "beyond" the square bracket. The main limitation is that `input` itself knows nothing about the terminal; it just reads from standard input, which is line-buffered. `input` returns nothing until a complete line is entered; until then, it just waits for the terminal to send *something*. A library like `curses` provides much more exact handling; for instance, it can stop responding to key presses if you try to type beyond the `]` in your prompt.

Comment: This doesn't work in most terminals as you said. In the same way, if you're terminal doesn't support ANSI escape sequences, does that mean you can't type in the input?

Comment: You'll be able to type the input. The prompt, however, will probably look something like `[[s ][u`, depending exactly how the terminal displays the escape character. `curses` is recommended because it uses information about your current terminal to output the correct escape sequences.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I can type in it when I run in terminal

Comment: With this solution, the user will type over the closing bracket instead of it moving to continue to enclose the output, correct?

Comment: Correct: after `input` prints the prompt, it blocks until the user hits enter. It's not monitoring keystrokes, nor is there anyway to specify any action to take if it were.

Comment: What is curses module? What is it used for? I am not able to import curses, so I tried installing that module using pip but it displayed this error message in the terminal ```ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement curses (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for curses```

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet, using `curses`, will handle standard visible ascii characters, deleting characters, and newline (for submit).

```py
from curses import wrapper

def prompt(stdscr, prompt_template="--> [ {} ]"):
    user_inp = ""
    display_str = prompt_template.format(user_inp)

    stdscr.addstr(0, 0, display_str)
    while True:
        inp_ch = stdscr.getch()

        # standard ASCII characters
        if 32 <= inp_ch <= 126:
            user_inp += chr(inp_ch)
        elif inp_ch in (8, 127, 263): # BS, DEL, Key_Backspace
            user_inp = user_inp[:-1]
        elif inp_ch == 10: # is newline, enter pressed
            break
        else: # all other characters are ignored
            continue

        display_str = prompt_template.format(user_inp)
        stdscr.erase()
        stdscr.addstr(0, 0, display_str)
        stdscr.refresh()

    return user_inp

print(wrapper(prompt))
```